# Jquery and html5 session storage to show last state selected in the json drop down box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following dropdown list code which dynamically get populated from JSON data . I am storing the date in html5 session storage.  I need to remember and show the last item in drop down list that was "selected"  .

Currently it showing incorrectly as  just `<option value="">Select Country</option>`

```
   <select name="country" class="dropdownselect" >
         <option value="">Select Country</option>   
             <option value="Afghanistan" selected="selected">Afghanistan</option>
             <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
             <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
             ....
             ......
     </select>
```

For example if the user had selected "Albania"
 based on localstorage value I want to display as  `<option value="Albania" selected>Albania</option>`
I want it to remember  and show the last item selected when the user comeback to the page, as long as it show the last selected item .

JS
//THIS populate the drop down country list dynamically
AJAX Service

```
    window.getCountry = function(URL) {       
        var country =URL +"/services/GetCountry";
        console.log("country " +country); 
        $.ajax({
            url: country,
            dataType: "json",
             cache: false,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                $('#country').empty();
                $('#country').append($('<option>').text("-Select Country-").attr('value', ''));    
                jQuery.each(data, function(k,v) {

   $('#country').append($('<option>').text(v.nameName).attr('value', v.countryFullname));

                 });       
        },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('FAILED to get  JSON from AJAX call' + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

            }
        });       

       }   

     $(document).ready(function() {
        var item = window.localStorage.getItem('country');
      console.log("item "+ item);
        $('select[name=country]').val(item);

        $('select[name=country]').change(function() {
           window.localStorage.setItem('country', $(this).val());
          console.log("item "+ item);



        });

        getCountry(some url);//this create the dropw down list dynamically

    });
```

HTML BIT-  This get dynamically populated from

**Problem** is  no matter what i select the last time , it always shows as  "Select Country" as the selected. Can someone help?

Comment: What's the problem?  This seems to work.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup It should dynamically add selected to the item. currently it not adding selected to the item that was selected

Comment: Why do you need `selected` added to the item.  It's a single select option.  Which ever one is selected is the value.  And that works.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup - it not showing the selected item for me in the dropdown even though the value is there in localstorage. the drop dhow this <option value="">Select Country</option> instead of this <option value="Albania"  >Albania</option> as the user have selected. I want it to remmeber  and show the last item selected when the user comeback to the page

Comment: It works perfectly, in firefox and chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/4puzx1zm/1/ and even ie11. Line i've added didn't changed behavior it just adds attribute 'selected'. Your script worked ok, even before it...

Comment: @nevermind - I updated it still shows as <option> select country</option> as the selected. any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) method instead

```js
var item = 'Albania';
$('select[name="country"] option[value="' + item + '"]').prop('selected', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="country" class="dropdownselect" >
  <option value="">Select Country</option>   
  <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
  <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you. but for some reason it never show the last selected item. It always show as  "Select Country". :(